# Wordpress get post category by post id

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to get the categories of one post in Wordpress.

The view I am currently in has more posts and I do have access to the post `ID` (which is a string for some reason).

I have tried these functions, but they come back without or incorrect data:

- [`get_the_category($result->ID)`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/)
- [`wp_get_post_categories($result->ID)`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_categories/)
- `get_category(wp_get_post_categories($result->ID)[0])->name`
- [`get_the_category_list(intval($result->ID))`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category_list/)

And all kinds of other ridiculous functions and user suggestions.

(where `$result->ID` results in `string (4) '1029'`

I just want some function to get the category of a post in a simple string from the integer value of a post.

Please keep your answer simple, I do not have much experience with Wordpress. (I do have reasonable experience with PHP and other frameworks)

Comment: @vico Can you tell me why this would work? This function only returns an empty string. I have converted the ID string to an int.

Answer (score 2):

The construct to fetch all of the categories for a specific post ID is dependent upon if you are in [the Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) or not.

Assumption: I'm going to assume that `$result->ID` is a post ID.

### Option 1

You use [`get_the_category`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/), which is a wrapper for `get_terms()`.  Use it like this:

```
$categories = get_the_category( (int) $result->ID );
```

It will give you an array of the `WP_Term` objects for each of the assigned terms (categories).

### Option 2

You can also use [`wp_get_post_categories`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_categories/) like this:

```
wp_get_post_categories( (int) $result->ID );
```

This construct is a wrapper for `wp_get_object_terms`. It returns an array of assigned term IDs.  You'd then have to get the category using each term ID, using `get_term( $term_id );` like this:

```
foreach( (array) wp_get_post_categories( (int) $result->ID ) as $term_id ) {
    $category = get_term( $term_id );
    // do stuff.
}
```

### Choice

Option 1 is the better choice as you get the array of the term objects without having to do a `foreach` loop.

### What if no categories returned?

If you are not getting categories back in your SQL result, check in the backend that the post ID actually has categories.

Comment: `get_categories()` results in all the categories their terms (not only the ones related to the post). and `wp_get_post_categories results` in an empty array. I am getting my posts by SQL if it matters.

Comment: @MegaXLR Doh. Updated. It's actually get_the_category( $post_id ); . Make sure that the ID actually has attached categories if you are getting an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get the **category**

'global $post;
$category_detail=get_the_category( $post->ID );`