# Display custom post type categories (terms) in loop

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy-terms

I am using the following code to load all the posts from a custom post type, in this loop I show a title but I also want to show the categories (terms) that are connected to this particular post but I can't seem to make it work

**Loop:**

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'fotoalbum', 'showposts'=> '-1' ); $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php $i=1; ?>
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php if($i==1 || $i%3==1) echo '<div class="row">' ;?>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a><br/>
        ! HERE I WANT THIS POSTS CATEGORY !
    </div>

<?php if($i%3==0) echo '</div>';?>
<?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**I tried:**

```
<?php echo $term->name; ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress get post category by post id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41040934/wordpress-get-post-category-by-post-id)

Comment: do you need to display custom taxonomy or built in "category"?

Comment: @Matts thank you for your time to look into my question but this concerned a custom post type and its terms (categories), not a standard post category

Comment: @Artem I meant the terms (categories) not taxonomy, sorry, I updates the text and the title

Comment: @ErwinvanEkeren I did understand what you were asking, but I should've commented instead of marking it as duplicate. The option 1 answer get_the_category() link leads to the wordpress function which states.  "Note: This function only returns results from the default "category" taxonomy. For custom taxonomies use get_the_terms()."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use get_the_terms()  for getting category
    you can get this by below code...
    you need to put second argument a custom post-type's category slug
    you can refer this link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/

```
    <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'fotoalbum', 'showposts'=> '-1' ); $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php $i=1; ?>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php if($i==1 || $i%3==1) echo '<div class="row">' ;?>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a><br/>
        ! HERE I WANT THIS POSTS CATEGORY !
        <?php 
        $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category-slug' ); // second argument is category slug of custom post-type
        if(!empty($terms)){
        foreach($terms as $term){
            echo $term->name.'<br>';
        }
        }
        ?>
    </div>

    <?php if($i%3==0) echo '</div>';?>
    <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```